# WAMP server suddenly stops working

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I was working with WAMP server and wordpress yesterday and today when I started WAMP the database get an error.

When I run wamp status I get this:
[image]

And in MySQL log I get:

```
2017-03-30T23:30:44.499590Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 0
2017-03-30T23:30:44.507591Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-03-30T23:30:44.509591Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-03-30T23:30:44.510591Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-03-30T23:30:44.511591Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-03-30T23:30:44.511591Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Please Help Me.
Thanks

Note: is not a problem of Skype!

Comment: have you run the server ?

Comment: Did you start skype?If so,turn it off

Comment: Mihai Is not a problem of skype. I've already change the port of skype.
John Jow What do you mean when you say run the server? Wampserver is running and the color of the icon is green so I could say that is working good but not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try to change the root password of your mysql. 
Go to the mysql console. You'll see that mysql asks you for a password, but leave it empty (press enter). After that, use this statement "SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_new_password');"
Once you do that, you can access to phpmyadmin with the user "root" and the new password you chose. Now, feel free to update/delete the user that was giving you problems.